# Qt - Check internet connection and create Threads

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I need to create a background task in my Qt app... I want to know if I have Internet connection each 5s. So I searched for QThread and QNetworkSession. 
Now I have:

```
QNetworkConfigurationManager mgr;
QNetworkConfiguration ap = mgr.defaultConfiguration();
QNetworkSession *session = new QNetworkSession(ap);
session->open();
qDebug() << "session: " << session->state();
```

If state is 3, I think I'm connected to Internet... But I'm not sure.

What I want to know is if this code really does want I need, if there is a better way to do it, and if using QThread is ok to run it in background...
If possible and QThread is the best way, can you shown me how to use QThread?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do small things in regular intervals, then using a `QTimer` is way more straight forward than using a thread.

However, have you had a look at `QNetworkConfigurationManager::onlineStateChanged()`?